# Insert auto genetated form field values into database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hello i want to insert generated field form values into my mysql database. it gets the number of customers into a dropdown box  and generate a set of fields based on the dropdown value. If the dropdown value is 2 then form fields will be repeated and all the filled data should go to the database. can anyone help me to insert these into the database.

database connection is established and working fine.

main.php
javascript Part

```js
//when the webpage has loaded do this
$(document).ready(function() {
  //if the value within the dropdown box has changed then run this code            
  $('#num_cat').change(function() {
    //get the number of fields required from the dropdown box
    var num = $('#num_cat').val();

    var i = 0; //integer variable for 'for' loop
    var html = ''; //string variable for html code for fields 
    //loop through to add the number of fields specified
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
      //concatinate number of fields to a variable
      html += '<h3 style="weight:bold;color:#0080FF; text-align: center;">CUSTOMER NO ' + i + '</h3> <br/> \n';
      html += 'First Name ' + ': <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="first_name" name="AgclifName' + i + '" />';
      html += 'Last Name ' + ': <input class="form-control"  type="text" id="first_name" name="AgclilName' + i + '" /><br/> \n';
      html += 'NIC / Passport Number ' + ': <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Agclinicpassport' + i + '"/><br/>';
      html += 'Nationality ' + ': <input class="form-control" type="text" name="AgcliNationality' + i + '"/><br/>';
      html += 'Age ' + ': <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Agcliage' + i + '"/><br/>';
      html += 'Weight' + ': <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Agcliweight' + i + '"/><br><br/><hr class="style13">';

    }

    //insert this html code into the div with id catList
    $('#catList').html(html);
  });
});
```

---

html part

```html
<form method="post" action="action.php">
  <div class='form-group'>
    <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='id_num_of_cus'>Number of Customers:</label>
    <div class='col-md-8'>
      <div class='col-md-3'>
        <div class='form-group internal'>
          <select class='form-control' id="num_cat" name="num_cat" style="width: 200%;" required>
            <option value="0">- SELECT -</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="catList"></div>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <div class='col-md-offset-4 col-md-3'>
      <button class='btn-lg btn-primary' type='submit' value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-3'>
      <button class='btn-lg btn-danger' style='float:right' type='reset'>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

Mysql part

```
foreach($_POST['num_cat'])
{
    // your insert query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblcsdetails (fname, lname, nicpass,nationality,age,weight) VALUES (' $_POST[AgclifName]',' $_POST[AgclilName]',' $_POST[Agclinicpassport]',' $_POST[AgcliNationality]',' $_POST[Agcliage]',' $_POST[Agcliweight]')";
}
```